# Why does compiling a header file with a D option result in a much bigger file than using a C wrapper for the header?

Tags: c, gcc

I have this C file that serves as a wrapper for a header file:

```
#define SOME_CONTROL_FLAG
#include "thefile.h"
```

If I compile with this:

```
gcc -I. -c -o thefile.o thefile.c
```

I get a 9 kB object file. However, if I do this instead:

```
gcc -I. -c -D SOME_CONTROL_FLAG -o thefile.o thefile.h
```

I get a 3 MB object file!  That's ~300 times larger.  Aren't those two command lines supposed to yield the same thing?

Comment: Maybe the symbol you're defining makes it such that a lot more code is included.  E.g., `#ifdef SOME_CONTROL_FLAG /* lots of code */ #endif`.

Comment: I can see why that comment is getting upvotes, but as Urhixidur noted in an answer, the issue here is actually due to GCC (quite reasonably) compiling the header file as a header file as opposed to compiling it as a C code.

Comment: In general, defining a symbol can indeed have lots of consequences in the code streaming into the compiler. But in this particular case, the .c file and the .h with -D #define precisely the same variable, so it should make no difference.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying in that last comment.  If the compilation of `c-header` files does not involve first running through the C preprocessor, then the `-D` won't make a difference when you're compiling a `c-header`.  When you're compiling `c` files, the C preprocessor is run, so the `-D` does make a difference.

Comment: Consider the two alternate compilations: `gcc -I. -c -o thefile.o thefile.c` where `thefile.c` is: `#define SOME_CONTROL_FLAG #include "thefile.h"` compared to `gcc -I. -c -x c -D SOME_CONTROL_FLAG -o thefile.o thefile.h`. The two yield precisely the same `thefile.o`, except for one byte (because the source file's name is embedded in the .o).

Clearer?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you're trying to say.  When you compile a C file that `includes some header, you're running the header through the C preprocessor and keeping the resulting code.  When you compile a header file, you're compiling a header file.  Just because a .c file and a .h file are written in the same language doesns't mean that "compiling a c source file" and "compiling a c header file" do the same thing or have the same kinds of output.

Comment: I'm on dangerous ground, because I haven't done much with compiled headers, but it seems to me that if you compile a header file with the contents `#ifdef FOO /* a */ #else /* b */ #endif`, then the compiled header still needs to contain both `a` and `b`, so that when you _include_ the compiled header from a source file later, it can do the right thing based on whether `FOO` is defined or not.  It's not about being smaller;  it's about being faster for the compiler to process.  Compiling the same thing as a C source is producing an object file with `a` or `b` and the other is gone.

Comment: In short, the result of compiling something as a header is a compiled header, and the result of compiling something as source is executable object code.  They're different _kinds_ of things, and what the preserve from the original input file is different.

Comment: Yes, a compiled header (`.cph`) is a different beast than an executable. I was trying to compile the `.h` directly to an executable, as if it were a `.c` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because gcc decides what to do with the input based on its extension, silly me. The true equivalent compilation line is:

```
gcc -I. -c -D SOME_CONTROL_FLAG -x c -o thefile.o thefile.h
```

Where -x c tells gcc to treat the .h as a .c

The resulting object files are identical save for one byte, because the file's name is included (in the debug info, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

### In general, compilation with different symbols compiled different code

Consider the following code.  If `FOOBAR` is defined, then there's *more* code in the file to compile (after the preprocessor preprocesses it):

```c
#ifdef FOOBAR

int foo(int bar) {
  return bar + bar;
}

#endif

int bar(int baz) {
  return 1+baz;
}
```

Compiling with FOOBAR defined changes the size of the output.  Without FOOBAR, it's 1232, and with FOOBAR, it's 1328.  That's not a huge difference, but it is a difference.

```
$ gcc -c code.c -o code.o
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1232 Oct 29 13:19 code.o

$ gcc -DFOOBAR -c code.c -o code.o
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user 1328 Oct 29 13:19 code.o
```

If there's lots of conditional code, this could be very significant.  For instance, defining symbols might cause lots of platform specific code to be included, and not defining symbols might leave function implementations as stubs.

### Compiling different *types* of code produces different code sizes

*Note: this portion is based on [Urhixidur's (the OP's) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665374/1281433). I felt that a bit more elaboration on it was in order.*

Another aspect that can lead to different compiled object sizes is what GCC is actually compiling.  In your example

```
gcc -I. -c -D SOME_CONTROL_FLAG -o thefile.o thefile.h
```

a header file is being compiled, and GCC detects that it's compiling with the `c-header` language based on the file extension.  However, the fact that you're compiling a header file and producing a `.o` file suggests that you want to compile this as C, in which case you should use GCC's `-x` option.  About it the man page says:

```
 -x language
           Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix).  This option applies to all
           following input files until the next -x option.  Possible values for language are:

                   c  c-header  cpp-output
                   c++  c++-header  c++-cpp-output
                   objective-c  objective-c-header  objective-c-cpp-output
                   objective-c++ objective-c++-header objective-c++-cpp-output
                   assembler  assembler-with-cpp
                   ada
                   f77  f77-cpp-input f95  f95-cpp-input
                   go
                   java

       -x none
           Turn off any specification of a language, so that subsequent files are handled according to their file name suffixes (as they are if -x has not been used at all).
```

Based on this, and the code I used in the first section, we can observe the *drastic* size difference that happens when we compile your code as `c` or as `c-header`:

```
$ gcc -c code.h -o code.o # as a header
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1470864 Oct 29 14:04 code.o

$ gcc -c -x c code.h -o code.o # as c code
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1232 Oct 29 14:04 code.o
```

Note that compiling (as a header) doesn't seem to be affected by the symbol definition though:

```
$ gcc -c code.h -o code.o
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1470864 Oct 29 14:06 code.o

$ gcc -DFOOBAR -c code.h -o code.o
$ ls -l code.o 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1470864 Oct 29 14:06 code.o
```